# Short user name with htaccess rewrite blocking other urls and fall under infinite redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create a short URL like `http://www.domain.com/user`
for that I m using

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.-]+)/?$ profile.php?userId=$1 [NC,R=301]
```

and this rule is working as expected.

But when I hit the other pages like `http://www.domain.com/members`, it will display an error in FF saying multiple header redirect.

Here is my full code (omits the headers)

```
RewriteRule ^default/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^members/?$ allmemberlist.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.-]+)/?$ profile.php?userId=$1 [NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^default/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^members/?$ allmemberlist.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ profile.php?userId=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `R=301` will redirect externally to your internal URI so you don't really need it.
- You need to skip real files/directories from this rewrite.

Comment: No luck, FF replies "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."... I can't see the page `http://www.domain.com/members`

Comment: Do you more rules than shown here? What is location of this .htaccess? Is `/members` a directory?

Comment: Yes..those are common like "Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"" and "Order allow,deny", I guess these are not causing any harm to rewrite rules. All the files under root directory..there are no sub directory..

Comment: ADDITION: I am using a sub domain where the htaccess file is stored. The top lines are looks like something: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#Options -Indexes

Comment: Ok try this in a new browser to avoid caching issues and also show your complete .htaccess for subdomain. Also tell which URL is causing redirection.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine on subdomain, happy to accept your answer.